# How to set global preferences in a XULRunner app

Tags: xul, xulrunner

Usually we set XULRunner app preferences:

```js
var pref = Cc["@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1"].getService(Ci.nsIPrefBranch);
pref.setBoolPref(name,value);
```

But these preferences are stored in the user profile. This means that the preference will be lost if you create a new XULRunner app profile.

Is there a way to set preferences globally or share preference between profiles?

Answer (score 1):

XULRunner stores all data in profile - starting from scratch when a new profile is created is the whole point of it. You should really reconsider storing data outside the user profile, normally that's unexpected and simply a bad idea.

But if you really want to do it then you are on your own, you need to store a custom file somewhere outside the user profile. For example, you could store a file in user's home directory:

```js
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm");
var file = FileUtils.getFile("Home", ["data.txt"]);
// Write to file here
```

That file would be shared for all profiles of this computer user. For more information see the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Code_snippets/File_I_O).

Note that even this approach won't give you a way to share preferences between different users on the same computer - normally there are no directories that all users are guaranteed to have write access to.

Comment: yes, 
finally i use nsIPrefService.savePrefFile save profile preferences to an file.
and then use nsIPrefService.readUserPrefs to load preferences when app onload.
it is ugly way, but it solved my problem.